# How do I change the C# version in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, c#-10.0

I'm currently writing a project in C# 7.3 but I need to change it to C# 10.0

When I go to my project's properties' advanced build settings, the option to change the language version is disabled. I'm not sure why it's grayed out, but I don't know how to manually change the C# version. If someone could help, that would be great, thanks!

[Screenshot of the advanced build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsHGp.png)

Comment: Does this one help?: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#override-a-default

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. Either I put it in the wrong place (the app.config file), or I did it wrong.

Comment: Did you install .NET 6? What do you see of you click the _Why can't I use a different version?_ link

Comment: *"I put it in the wrong place (the app.config file)"*. Perhaps you should read the page that's linked and do what it says instead.

Comment: Does VS 2019 support .NET 6? I was under the impression that it only supported up to .NET 5, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: c# 10 is supported on .NET 6 and up. You likely need to retarget your project to .NET 6

Comment: Any reason you need to use VS2019 rather than VS2022?

Answer (score 4):

Taken directly from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)

The compiler determines a default based on these rules:

| Target framework | version | C# language version default |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .NET | 7.x | C# 11 |
| .NET | 6.x | C# 10 |
| .NET | 5.x | C# 9.0 |
| .NET Core | 3.x | C# 8.0 |
| .NET Core | 2.x | C# 7.3 |
| .NET Standard | 2.1 | C# 8.0 |
| .NET Standard | 2.0 | C# 7.3 |
| .NET Standard | 1.x | C# 7.3 |
| .NET Framework | all | C# 7.3 |

> C# 10 is supported only on .NET 6 and newer

You haven't provided the target framework for your project. But you likely need to retarget your project to a framework that supports C#10

Answer (score 1):

You can try to edit the .csproj file by adding something like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

C#10 is already the default language version if your target framework is .NET 6, provided you're not overriding it with the `LangVersion` entry as mentioned in other answers. If you're not targeting .NET 6 or compiling with VS/Build Tools 2022, you'll need to upgrade those first in order to have proper C#10 support.

If you *are* attempting to set the C# language version manually, keep in mind the default can be overridden in two locations (or [programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/vslangproj80.csharpprojectconfigurationproperties3.languageversion?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)): the [**project file**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#edit-the-project-file) (aka `ProjectName.csproj`), or a [**Directory.Build.props**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#configure-multiple-projects) file (for explicitly overriding multiple projects at once). If the aforementioned props file exists, check it as well as your project file to ensure you don't have conflicting entries.

In your case, there's really no reason to manually specify the language version; just upgrade your compiler and use the default. If at that point you still find the project targeting anything < C#10, be aware that the culprit isn't necessarily confined to being the project file.